could $|2U+2V|$ be smaller than $|U-V|$?
I am interested in whether there are any conclusion/conterexample that the sum&difference of finite integer sets by more times is smaller than the sum&difference by less times.
The question I am actually thinking about is the following: Is there any example of finite integer set $U,V$, s.t. $U-V=\{1,2,...,m\}$, $U+U+V+V\neq\{1,2,...,m\}\pmod m$ for some m.
I think I knew nothing when comparing 4 sums and 2 difference, even the $U=V$ case or without modulo $m$ case.
when $U=\{x^2,x^2+1:x\in Z\}$, $V=\{x^2:x\in Z\}$, then $U-V=Z$, and $7*4^n \notin U+V+V$, this may show that 3 sums may be smaller than 2 difference? (though these are two infinite sets)

We have $2U+2V = 2(U+V)$ and $|U-V| \leq \frac{|U+V|^3}{|U||V|}$. Maybe we can find from this bounds on the doubling constant of $U+V$? Not sure if they are sufficient for anything, though

According to More differences than multiple sums, Imre Z. Ruzsa this is possible, even with $U=V$.

Thanks a lot! This is the result I'm exactly looking for.
